# Is it possible to use the Microsoft Kinect SDK with Metro Style applications?

Tags: windows-8, kinect, microsoft-metro

I was wondering if it is possible to use the Kinect SDK with Metro Style applications and if smartphone and tablets will have support for Kinect.

Comment: Where would you plug the Kinect in on a smartphone?

Comment: Many tablets have USB ports, I don't really understand the reason for the downvotes. Metro applications are meant to run both in desktop and mobile platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible and someone has done it. But not directly on Metro UI as far as I known (April 4, 2012)

Microsoft released [`Kinect for Windows 7 SDK`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/) in June, 2011. So, we know that Microsoft is targeting to utilize Kinect for PC controlling. Since Windows 8 is more touch driven than any other previous release of Windows, it should be in their target to introduce Kinect as one of the Windows 8 control device.

In addition, Metro UI has already been introduced on XBOX. We can see that Kinect works really well with XBOX Metro UI. Given that Kinect works well with Windows 7 and Metro UI on XBOX, it is not hard to imagine Kinect to work with `Windows 8`. Especially we know that most of the `.Net 4.5` applications should still be working on the traditional desktop interface of Windows 8. (A [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nyLDaB-t4c) on youtube also demonstrated how they used Kinect on Windows 8 traditional desktop interface and Metro Application by using a service)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the web socket implementation but I was hoping there was an actual native support for Kinect in Metro style apps.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was the intention to bring it in natively for Metro apps -- especially considering the (arguably more useful) entire `System.Data` namespace is absent

Comment: @Giohji As far as I known, the web socket implementation is the only way for now, but the Kinect SDK is still young and Win8 is still at Preview stage, we can only hope that MSFT provide metro kinect API. Since they are applying Metro API everywhere, I guess they get their soon and even make the apps cross XBOX and windows. Who knows :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw You have a good point, but this Win8 is still at preview stage. So we can hope MSFT will come up certain Metro Kinect API. :)

Answer (score 3):

We've developed a project called "KinectMetroApp" that helps to use kinect to control Metro UI on Windows 8.
Plz find below the post that describes the project.

http://wiseteamtn.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/kinect-your-metro-style-app/

Also, a recent article on channel 9 speaks about this Topic.

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Kinect-your-Metro

Comment: I downloaded your app from http://kinectmetroapp.codeplex.com/, but sorry it give erros, help will be appreciated, as I am too fresh into it